# How to do such a sorting with arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

These are my arrays:

```
$foo1 = array (5) {
          [0] => 'foo1',
          [1] => 'foo2',
          [2] => 'foo3',
          [3] => 'foo4',
          [4] => 'foo5'
        }

$foo2 = array (5) {
          [0] => 200,
          [1] => 130,
          [2] => 110,
          [3] => 80,
          [4] => 20
        }

$foo3 = array (5) {
          [0] => 610,
          [1] => 630,
          [2] => 500,
          [3] => 800,
          [4] => 200
        }
```

This is just to signify what it looks like, not my actual PHP code.

Now, what I want to do is this - I want to order the array `$foo1` by the total sum of the arrays `$foo2` and `$foo3`. But this is not the same as my last question, as this time, if the value in the array `$foo2` is less than 100 or the value in the array `$foo3` is less than 600, I don't want it anywhere near the top. I want it placed behind all the last ones which have the value in the array `$foo2` as above 100, and the value in the array `$foo3` as above 600. So in the case of the following array, the result would be:

```
$foo1 = array (5) {
          [0] => 'foo1',
          [1] => 'foo2',
          [2] => 'foo4',
          [3] => 'foo3',
          [4] => 'foo5'
        }
```

If you didn't fully understand above, this is why. Because the value in the array `$foo2` with the same key as `foo1` in the array `$foo1` is above 100, and the value in the array `$foo3` with the same key as `foo1` in the array `$foo1` is above 600, and it has the highest sum altogether. `foo2` is the next one, because it is the next element which has the same index keys which fulfil the requirements, and have the highest sum. `foo4` is next, because none of the other rows fulfil the requirements, and `foo4`'s equivalent keys in the other arrays have the largest sum out of the rows which don't fulfil the requirements. `foo3` and `foo5` are 4th and 5th for the same reason.

Hope I'm not being too specific, and any help?

Comment: Is it necessary to preserve key values for foo1?  Or do you just need the values in that sorted order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine them first, add a flag (`"tail"=>true/false`), and sort it.

```
function special_sort($arr1,$arr2,$arr3)
{
    $arr=array();
    foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val)
    {
        $arr[$key]=array("val"=>$val,"sum"=>($arr2[$key]+$arr3[$key]),"tail"=>(($arr2[$key]<100 || $arr3[$key]<600)?true:false));
    }
    usort($arr,function($a,$b){
        if($a["tail"] && !$b["tail"])
            return 1;
        elseif(!$a["tail"] && $b["tail"])
            return -1;
        elseif($a["sum"]>$b["sum"])
            return -1;
        elseif($a["sum"]<$b["sum"])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    });
    return $arr;
}
```

Test result:

```
$foo1=array("foo1","foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5");
$foo2=array(200,130,110,80,20);
$foo3=array(610,630,500,800,200);
print_r(special_sort($foo1,$foo2,$foo3));
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [val] => foo1
            [sum] => 810
            [tail] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [val] => foo2
            [sum] => 760
            [tail] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [val] => foo4
            [sum] => 880
            [tail] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [val] => foo3
            [sum] => 610
            [tail] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [val] => foo5
            [sum] => 220
            [tail] => 1
        )

)
```

You'll have to take out the "val" value if you want. That shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Sorry for asking such a tedious and wordy question. Awesome answer all the same.

Comment: also, how would I sort the other two arrays according to how the first one was sorted, and return them as well somehow?

Comment: @think123 In that case I would rather save all three values into `$arr` in `special_sort()` (right now I'm only saving value from `$foo1`) and then extra them out after sorting.

Comment: @think123 Another way would be to do an `array_search($arr[1]["val"],$foo1)` to fetch the key from the original `$foo1` and gain corresponding access to `$foo2` and `$foo3`.

Comment: I just put this in my code, and its showing me a Parse Error, because of the embedded function. Why is this?

Comment: @think123 What version of PHP are you using? If you're using PHP<5.3, write the embedded function in a normal way and refer to it by it's name: `function embed_sort(){...} function special_sort(){...usort($arr,"embed_sort");}`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [usort()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which would also make your code easier to read than the other examples.